# 'Idle in transaction' connections history in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, locking

I want to check 'idle in trasanction' connections on a particular day in past. Had an outage a couple of days back accompanied by a spike in 'idle in transaction' connections. Wanted to understand which db queries lead to this.

**PostgreSQL version**: "PostgreSQL 12.14 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit"

Comment: where your PostgreSQL database is deployed (on-premises or on a cloud service like Azure) and if you have logging enabled for it?

Comment: Hi @PrzemysławDoczkal we are using AWS RDS. Not sure if logging is enabled on it. How to enable it if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not retain the history of statements that were executed in a given transaction, so the only way to get that is to log all statements. It is never an SQL statement that leads to sessions that stay `idle in transaction`, but the client's failure to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.